# Can floating point multiplication by zero be optimised at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, floating-point, multiplication

I am writing an algorithm to find the inverse of an nxn matrix. Let us take the specific case of a 3x3 matrix.

When you invert a matrix by hand, you typically look for rows/columns containing one or more zeros to make the determinant calculation faster as it eliminates terms you need to calculate.

Following this logic in C/C++, if you identify a row/column with one or more zeros, you will end up with the following code:

```
float term1 = currentElement * DetOf2x2(...);
//           ^
//           This is equal to 0.
//
// float term2 = ... and so on.
```

As the compiler cannot know `currentElement` will be zero at compile time, it cannot be optimised to something like `float term = 0;` and thus the floating point multiplication will be carried out at runtime.

My question is, will these zero values make the floating point multiplication faster, or will the multiplication take the same amount of time regardless of the value of `currentElement`? If there is no way of optimising the multiplication at runtime, then I can remove the logic that searches for rows/columns containing zeros.

Comment: Depends on the FPU design.  Some will be faster and some won't.

Comment: Why not make a test and see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float term1 = currentElement * DetOf2x2(...);
```

The compiler will call `DetOf2x2(...)` even if currentElement is 0: that's sure to be far more costly than the final multiplication, whether by 0 or not.  There are multiple reasons for that:

- `DetOf2x2(...)` may have side effects (like output to a log file) that need to happen even when `currentElement` is `0`, and
- `DetOf2x2(...)` may return values like the Not-a-Number / NaN sentinel that should propagate to `term1` anyway (as noted first by Nils Pipenbrinck)

Given `DetOf2x2(...)` is almost certainly working on values that can only be determined at run-time, the latter possibility can't be ruled out at compile time.

If you want to avoid the call to `Detof2x2(...)`, try:

```
float term1 = (currentElement != 0) ? currentElement * DetOf2x2(...) : 0;
```

Comment: I doubt the compiler would generate a conditional move here.

Comment: This is right - the point of looking for zeroes isn't to avoid the multiply, it's to avoid the `DetOf2x2()` calculation.

Comment: Regarding Potatoswatter's comment to user57368's answer, will the asm branch generated by the `?:` operator be faster than simply multiplying it out anyway given that `DetOf2x2` merely contains the typical: 1 / (a * d - b * c) ?

Comment: @PLPiper: particularly if DetOf2x2 is inlined, it'll be a close call and the answer likely depends on your specific hardware: have to profile to find out.  (BTW - I assume you know that a*d != b*c before attempting the division....)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! DetOf2x2 will be inlined so I'll get profiling. (And yes, regarding the 1/0 issue!)

Answer (score 10):

The compiler is not allowed to optimize this unless the calculation is trival (e.g. all constants).

The reason is, that DetOf2x2 may return a NAN floating point value. Multiplying a NAN with zero does not return zero but a NAN again.

You can try it yourself using this little test here:

```
int main (int argc, char **args)
{
  // generate a NAN
  float a = sqrt (-1);

  // Multiply NAN with zero..
  float b = 0*a;

  // this should *not* output zero
  printf ("%f\n", b);
}
```

If you want to optimize your code, you have to test for zero on your own. The compiler will not do that for you.

Comment: I suppose with -O4 -ffast-math compiler can be made to ignore NaNs.

Answer (score 3):

Modern CPUs will actually handle a multiply-by-zero *very* quickly, more quickly than a general multiply, and *much* more quickly than a branch. Don't even bother trying to optimize this unless that zero is going to propagate through at least several dozen instructions.

Comment: But the zero *will* propagate through quite a few instructions, and a correctly-predicted branch executes in zero cycles whereas the multiply will likely execute in one versus two in the general case.

Comment: Regarding the qualitative 'much', assuming that `DetOf2x2` contains only the normal 1/(a*d-b*c), will the multiple floating point instructions still be faster than a branch? Or is that system-implementation-sepecific?

Comment: At the moment, I'm having trouble finding a source for the hardware optimization of a FP multiply-by-zero - that might only work for scalar integer instructions. Anyways, a 2x2 determinant is almost certainly too small of a calculation to be worth a branch to skip. For example, Intel's Sandy Bridge can do independent FP vector multiply, add, and shuffle all in the same clock cycle, so you can probably pipeline the computation of 3 2x2 determinants into an instruction sequence that will only take a dozen cycles. I'd recommend implementing the 3x3 determinant as a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Optimisations performed at runtime are known as JIT (just-in-time) optimisations. Optimisations performed at translation (compilation) are known as AOT (ahead-of-time) optimisations. You're referring to JIT optimisations. A compiler might introduce JIT optimisations into your machine code, but it's certainly a far more complex optimisation to implement than the common AOT optimisations. Optimisations are typically implemented based on significance, and this kind of "optimisation" might be seen to affect other algorithms negatively. C implementations aren't required to perform any of these optimisations.

You could provide the optimisation manually, which would be "the logic that searches for rows/columns containing zeros", or something like this: `float term1 = currentElement != 0 ? currentElement * DetOf2x2(...) : 0;`

Comment: There are also hardware optimizations. It seems he's asking about the ALU level. It's safe to say that C++ implementations don't perform JIT optimizations unless being run on an emulator.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Intel's C++ compiler certainly performs JIT optimisations.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Google tells me nothing, and such a feature should make the news. Profile-guided optimization (PGO) is another class between AOT and JIT, and the major vendors all implement that; is that what you mean?

Comment: Does this look like PGO to you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Criticism

Comment: No, that's just regular AOT optimization, performed several times with different machine descriptions. The result would be (in Apple terminology) a "fat binary" because it contains several copies of at least part of the program.

Comment: JIT optimization is when the program is profiled as it's run in the field, and the code is recompiled to speed up the most common case. In a native environment like C++, implementing that would make injection attacks easy. PGO is when the programmer profiles using a realistic testcase, and that is used for common-case analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The following construct is valid at compile time when the compiler can guess the value of "currentElement".

float term1 = currentElement ? currentElement * DetOf2x2(...) : 0;

If it cannot be guessed at compile time, it will be checked at run-time and the performance depends on processor architecture : the trade-off between a branch (include branch latency and the delay to rebuild the instruction pipeline can be up to 10 or 20 cycles) and flat code (some processors run 3 instructions per cycle) and hardware branch prediction (when the hardware supports branch prediction).

Since multiplications throughput is close to 1 cycle on a x86_64 processor, there is no perf differenec depending on operand values like 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 or 12345678.99. if such a difference exists, that would be perceived as a covert channel in cryptographic-style software.

GCC allows to check function parameters at compile time

inline float myFn(float currentElement, myMatrix M)

{

#if __builtin_constant_p(currentElement) && currentElement == 0.0

return 0.0;

#else

return currentElement * det(M);

#endif

}

you need to enable inlining and interprocedural optimizations in the compiler.